# Job listing has HTML tags without opening

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I built a little Google Chrome extension to notify me about new jobs with salaries (too bad your RSS feed doesn't include salary) and I have noticed that job listing page has some tags HTML tags without opening.

```
No li element in scope but a li end tag seen.
```

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fjobs

Comment: Yes, this is basic stuff. It ought to be in their test suite. However, this could depend on the HTML version. Are you sure you have used the correct HTML version when invoking the W3C validator?

Comment: Is it also the case when you are logged in?

Comment: Yep, `<li> ... </li>` inside a `<li> ... </li>`, near "`<div class="left-sidebar--sticky-container js-sticky-leftnav">`". It is probably [not legal in any version of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915242/alternative-for-having-a-li-inside-li-element-in-html-form/8915283#8915283). Or is it in HTML5?

Answer (score 3):

This wasn't a jobs related issue, it was a markup problem in Stack Overflow itself related to the sidebar. Fix is being deployed to production shortly. Thanks for the heads up!